# azure dedicated sql pool (sqldw) serializable table hint statement odd behavior

Tags: t-sql, locking, azure-synapse

platform: **azure**

product: **dedicated sql pool (sqldw)**

I have an odd behavior that would like a better understanding if anyone here knows. I'm trying to test if the serializable table hint works. I wasn't able to find any official documentation so I'm going to assume it isn't supported and the returned error seems to concur. That aside, my question is pertaining to the t-sql syntax.

If I execute this:

```
select *
from serialtest with (serializable)
order by session_id
```

I get this:

```
Msg 103022, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Parse error at line: 2, column: 26: serializable is not a recognized table or a view hint.
```

However, if I execute this, it works!?:

```
select *
from serialtest (serializable)
order by session_id
```

I'm simply querying a new table I just created. So unless there is some new syntax or hint that works without the "with" word then I'm dumbfounded. I also tested this hint and was able to update the table while this statement was still running which means the serializable hint is not actually working as it should.

So what exactly is this select statement doing with this "serializable" hint? I tried wrapping it around BEGIN TRANSACTION...COMMIT and still the same behavior.

Comment: Azure Synapse Analytics, dedicated SQL pools do not support table hints, I think what you're doing is accidentally giving the table name an alias of "(serializable)".

Comment: @wBob thanks for commenting. I thought the same thing prior and changed "serializable" to "tbla", I get this: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 110
Invalid column name 'tbla'.
Parameters supplied for object 'serialtest' which is not a function. If the parameters are intended as a table hint, a WITH keyword is required.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem/issue.

serializable is a locking hint, but serializable isn't a supported transaction isolation level on SQLDW/Dedicated Pool.

Read Uncommitted and READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT are.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-transactions

Other hints like this don't error i.e. dont need the 'WITH' - (READUNCOMMITTED) and (NOLOCK) for example.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Hints%20%28Transact-SQL%29%20-%20Query%201%20Remarks.%20Query%20hints,the%20query.%20The%20example%20uses%20the%20AdventureWorks2012%20database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Hints%20%28Transact-SQL%29%20-%20Query%201%20Remarks.%20Query%20hints,the%20query.%20The%20example%20uses%20the%20AdventureWorks2012%20database).

So what is it doing? I don't think its actually doing anything.
It looks like its being ignored.
If you look at the explain plan - the (serializable) hint is not being passed down to compute nodes.

Comment: I never thought to look at the explain plan however when I execute the query with the (NOLOCK) hint, I don't see "(NOLOCK)" in the explain plan either?

Comment: NOLOCK isnt a valid hint for SQLDW/SQL Dedicated Pools.   There are only a handful that do work.   I was just using it as an example of other hints that don't error, but also don't do anything either.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Could you point me to where I can see these handful of hints that do work? Appreciate your time.